# Implement JavaScript's string.prototype.includes and analyze the time complexity of it

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I wonder what's the time complexity for the string method `includes` in JavaScript, which determines whether one string may be found within another string.

e.g. 
`str1 = 'abcd'` `substr = 'bcd'`, `console.log(str1.includes(substr))` will output `true`

I tried to implement my own includes to get a better idea of how it works under the hood. Here is my attempt.

```
function includes(str, substr) {
  let i = 0
  let j = 0
  let match = 0

  while(i < str.length) {
    if(str[i] === substr[j]) {
      match++
      i++
      j++
      if(match === substr.length) return true
    } else if(str[i] === substr[0]) {
      match = 0
      j = 0
    } else {
      match = 0
      j = 0
      i++
    }
  }

  return false
}
```

so `console.log(includes('aaaabcd','aaaabc'))` will output `true`.

It seems to me that the time complexity here is `nm`, where `n` is the lenght of `str` and `m` is the length of `substr`.

Also I wonder if anyone has a more elegant algorithm to implement it. Maybe using a sliding window approach? I am not sure.

Comment: I don't think you can do any better.

Comment: The [polyfill on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Polyfill) just uses `.indexOf()` which may have a native code implementation and thus could be faster.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yea I am aware of the usage of `indexof` but I don't think it reduce the time complexity. `.indexOf()` is still a linear time operation

Comment: In terms of other algorithms, there is the Gusfield's z-algorithm and Boyer-Moore which can provide n+m worst-case time complexity (I think boyer-moore can even get as good as o(n/m) on _real text_)

Comment: Well, the time complexity isn't going to change much.  It's just how fast an implementation of that time complexity you can come up with.  And, you asked ***"if anyone has a more elegant implementation"*** and in my opinion, using `.indexOf()` is significantly more elegant.  FYI, the time complexity isn't quite `nm` because the comparison gets to bail as soon as you find a mismatch.  Best case is the string you're searching has 0 or 1 occurrences of the lead character in the match string in which case it's just slightly more than n.

Comment: FYI your `includes` implementation is incorrect, for example `includes("12121234", "12123")` should be `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Time complexity for this is O(n). I don't think it can get any better. But in your implementation I made a small change.

```
function includes(str, substr) {
  let i = 0
  let j = 0

  while(i < str.length) {
    if(str[i] === substr[j]) {
      i++
      j++
      if(j === substr.length) return true
    } else if(str[i] === substr[0]) {
      j = 0
    } else {
      j = 0
      i++
    }
  }

  return false
}
```